# Merging / copying different Core Data contexts

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've been reading several posts related to this, but I'm still not sure of how should I handle my scenario: I have a "root" context (the provided in `AppDelegate` by default) where I insert the objects I use and show throughout the app (this context is intended for read-only operations). My object's data come from several Web Services I periodically call, and whenever I need to call them and update my objects, I create a new context in a private queue to request and parse them:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator;

[privateContext performBlock: ^{
        // Call services and parse results
        // Insert objects in context
        // Save context
        });
    }];
```

When this finishes, I need to transfer the updates to my "root" context to keep showing it thoughout the app. I don't know how should I do this, I've been thiking about some options:

1. To "clean" the root context and fetch again all the objects.
2. To "clean" the root context and copy/duplicate somehow the private context to it
3. To manage some kind of merge policy

This last point sounds to be the most appropriate one, if there is not a better one... is there? Could somebody give me a clear example / tutorial / sample code of a similar scenario? I don't fully understand yet concurrency in Core Data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont u use a universal context? as in call the context from the app delegate? in such a way you dont have to worry about updating or inserting.

Comment: @SahebRoy Because I read that the recommendation is to use a context in a separated private queue to perform data updates and avoid blocking the main thread

Comment: Yes it is to be in a separate queue not in the main thread but you can use the universal context from app delegate to do so.
What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: @SahebRoy is it possible to do that once the context has its concurrency type already set?

Comment: Create a appdelegate obj and call the managecontext from that object, you will get the global managecontext and will be able to fetch update on your own. 
No point creating managecontext separatly as it will catch the only one

Comment: @SahebRoy but ASFAIK the default context in appDelegate is associated to main thread, so main thread will be blocked while I perform data updates by calling the Web Services I need, right?

Comment: Yes it is in the main queue, 
If you have to use multiple context then you better think about sqlite or something more heavy. performing core data on multiple managecontext is a bad idea.

Comment: @SahebRoy even if I directly use sqlite, I will have to manage concurrency... my app could need to update data while it is using it and I shouldn't block the UI... I mean, in my case I can't use the simple thing of showing a progress HUD while updating to prevent user from interacting with the app

Comment: If you use SQLite you can do all the update and fetching in a single background thread, but when u are fetching the data from SQLite and interacting with the view that will have to be done in the main thread but the lag is very very negligible, there wont be any lag in UI

Comment: @SahebRoy but you mean... stop using Core Data at all? Or you can keep using Core Data and directly handle the sqlite file for certain things?

Comment: I would recommend using core data for the lightweighted stuffs but for heavy duty stuff which u think would block the main thread go for sqlite,
But i still think running on main thread would be good, 
As when you are downloading user details which are absolutely required for an app to run, it is done in main thread as the app wont run witout fetching that data.
Depends on your app model